# Cant click bone name in three js

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber

**Problem**
Hi, I want an application where you click on a bone and it prints the bone name to the console. I am using three.js  The code below prints all the bone names but doesn't work if I click on a bone, what am I doing wrong?

**Currently**
I currently print all the bone names to the console.  This is done by traversing.

**Code**

```
const Character = ({ modelHierarchy }) => {
const { scene } = useThree();
const [model, setModel] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
  const loader = new GLTFLoader();
  loader.load('/character-kick.glb', (gltf) => {
    const bones = [];
    gltf.scene.traverse((object) => {
      if (object.isBone) {
        console.log('Bone name:', object.name);
        bones.push(object);
      }
    });

    setModel(gltf.scene);
    modelHierarchy.current = bones;
    console.log("Hierarchy with bones:", bones);
  });
}, [scene]);

return model ? <primitive object={model} /> : null;
};



const CharacterScene = () => {
const { camera, gl, scene } = useThree();
const [raycaster] = useState(() => new THREE.Raycaster());
const [selectedBone, setSelectedBone] = useState(null);
const modelHierarchy = useRef([]);

const getMousePosition = (event) => {
const rect = gl.domElement.getBoundingClientRect();
const x = ((event.clientX - rect.left) / rect.width) * 2 - 1;
const y = -((event.clientY - rect.top) / rect.height) * 2 + 1;

return new THREE.Vector2(x, y);
};

const onMouseDown = (event) => {
console.log("mouse down");
console.log("heir", modelHierarchy);
const mousePosition = getMousePosition(event);

// Update the picking ray with the camera and mouse position
raycaster.setFromCamera(mousePosition, camera);

// Find the closest intersected object in the model's hierarchy
const intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(modelHierarchy.current, true);
console.log("intersects", intersects);

if (intersects.length > 0) {
const closestIntersect = intersects[0];
const { object: mesh, point: intersectionPoint } = closestIntersect;

let closestBone = null;
let minDistance = Infinity;

mesh.skeleton.bones.forEach((bone) => {
  const distance = bone.getWorldPosition(new THREE.Vector3()).distanceTo(intersectionPoint);
  if (distance < minDistance) {
    closestBone = bone;
    minDistance = distance;
  }
});

if (closestBone) {
  setSelectedBone(closestBone);
  console.log('Selected bone:', closestBone.name);
} else {
  setSelectedBone(null);
}
} else {
  setSelectedBone(null);
}
};

  useEffect(() => {
  gl.domElement.addEventListener('mousedown', onMouseDown);

  return () => {
    gl.domElement.removeEventListener('mousedown', onMouseDown);
  };
}, [gl.domElement]);

return (
  <>
    <ambientLight />
    <pointLight position={[10, 10, 10]} />
    <Character modelHierarchy={modelHierarchy} />
    <Controls />
  </>
);
```